# ¿Por que count en Eloquent solo me devuelve un registro?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy en laravel 8, e intento hacer un conteo en eloquent pero solo me devuelve un registro.

```
$resultado=  Principal::select('usuario.nombre')
            ->where ('calificaciones', '>=', 0)
            ->leftjoin('usuario', 'usuario.id' , 'principal.usuarioId')
            ->groupBy('usuarioId')
            ->count();
```

Este codigo me devuelve :  18

Si lo hiciera en directamente en mysql, este me arroja varios registros.

```
SELECT COUNT(`calificaciones`), usuario.nombre from principal
INNER JOIN usuario on principal.usuarioId = usuario.id
where calificaciones >= 0
GROUP by `usuarioId`
```

Este codigo directo de MYSQL, me devuelve

```
COUNT(`calificaciones`) nombre
18                      Carlos Mundo
15                      Santiago Z
12                      Berto  QZ
5                       Miguel A
```

Como puedo escribir esta setencia en eloquent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método [`count()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-aggregates) devuelve el valor escalar de la consulta que le pasas.

Si deseas obtener el conteo de distintos grupos de valores basados en una condición, entonces tu query debe transformarse a esto:

```
$resultado=  Principal::selectRaw('COUNT(`calificaciones`) AS Conteo, usuario.nombre')
            ->where('calificaciones', '>=', 0)
            ->leftJoin('usuario', 'usuario.id' , 'principal.usuarioId')
            ->groupBy('usuario.nombre')
            ->get();
```

Donde:

- Al método `selectRaw` le pasamos las columnas que necesitamos, incluida aquella que se genera mediante una función de agregación
- En el agrupamiento lo hacemos por el nombre del usuario
- Al final usamos el método `get` el cual nos dará como salida una colección

Comment: Cuando lo hago asi: me marca un error:

"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'COUNT(calificaciones)' in 'field list' (SQL: select `COUNT(calificaciones)` as `Conteo`, `usuario.nombre` from `principal` where `calificaciones` > = 0 group by `trabajadorId`)"

Comment: Muchas gracias! ya realicé tus pasos.